# Laravel search on multiple tables using this scenario

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I want to search on "Table: employees > name" or "Table: jobs > company" of assigned jobs. What should I add to perform this? Is this a correct and optimized code to perform the task? This is my code:

**SearchController**

```
public function search_assigned_jobs($search=null)
{
  $result = AssignJob::with('jobs', 'employees')->whereHas('employees', function ($query) use ($search){
    $query->where('name', 'like', '%'.$search.'%');
      })->orWhereHas('jobs', function ($query) use ($search){
        $query->where('company', 'like', '%'.$search.'%');
      })->get();
 
    return $this->success($result);
}
```

**API Route**

```
Route::get('admin/search-assigned-jobs/{search?}', [SearchController::class, 'search_assigned_jobs']);
```

**Tables**
https://i.stack.imgur.com/F4Ptx.jpg

**Models**
https://i.stack.imgur.com/UnYyu.jpg